# can't link with a main executable file '/usr/local/bin/lua' for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, lua, dylib

I'm attempting to make a dylib using multiple files with the command:
`g++ -std=c++11 rewrite.cpp Utilities/*.cpp -fpermissive -I /Users/x/Desktop/lua-5.1 -L/Users/x/Desktop/libs /usr/local/bin/lua -lm -ldl -o /Users/x/Desktop/Code/Result.dylib -v`

However I'm encountering the error: `ld: can't link with a main executable file '/usr/local/bin/lua' for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: I think the error explains itself. The version of `lua` you are trying to link with is for a different platform that the rest of your code. Maybe you downloaded the wrong version?

Comment: It seems you're trying to make a dylib from a main executable file /usr/local/bin/lua. Does that work at all? If your original goal is to create a dylib for Lua, then don't link it with the lua binary. If the goal is to create a dylib that contains the Lua library, then use lublib.a instead. See examples in my libraries at https://web.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/

Comment: @john thank you, I had some issues installing the right version but I did it eventually.

Comment: @lhf it indeed did work, but I will consider using lublib.a in the future, thank you.

Comment: @lhf could you please elaborate about the usage of lublib.a and where i can compile/find it?

Comment: I meant liblua.a, which you should have already. Sorry for the noise.